# How prepare lib to be tree-shaking compatible?

Tags: typescript, webpack, plugins, tree-shaking

I have a plugin created with Typescript and I need activate Tree-shaking in [this plugin](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=nfetch@1.3.9).
Is there any way to enable this feature without webpack?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tree shaking is a process that bundlers apply in order to remove lib's unused code.

That means that as a lib you need to export a version (esm) that is tree-shakable, because you don't know what code your consumers will not use.

If your code gonna be used in both envs, node & browsers, you will need to export `cjs` (commonJS) version for node & `esm` (ES modules) version for browser use.

With typescript you can achieve that by running `tsc` twice with 2 separate configs:

```
// tsconfig.browser.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/esm/",
    ...
  }

}
```

```
// tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist/cjs/",
    ...
  }

}
```

Then specify the config for each run.

```
tsc -c ./tsconfig.browser.json
tsc -c ./tsconfig.node.json
```

In your `package.json` add 2 entries.

```
{
  ...
  module: "dist/esm/index.js",
  main: "dist/cjs/index.js"
  ...
}
```